# C# Firewall, delete specific entry

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

I am currently programming a windows-firewallmanager for a company.
Problem is, that I can only delete an entry by name and not by an INetFwRule object or something.
There are entries, that have the same name two times where one is for TCP and the other one for UDP and we might want to delete only one of them.
I could delete both and create one of them afterwards again, but I would not like to use that workaround.
Does anyone have an easy solution to this?

Comment: Can you filter by Name+Protocol?

Comment: Yes I can loop through all rules and filter during that

Comment: Append [TCP] and [UDP] to the rule names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only delete rules by name using the `INetFwRules` interface which seems to be a badly designed API because different rules can have the same name. A workaround is to filter the rules not only by name by also by the other properties that specifies the rule you want to delete. When you have found the rule to delete you can then rename the rule to a unique name using the `INetFwRule` interface.

You can then delete the rule using this unique temporary name.

Comment: I already thought of that too, but that is not proper programming. However it would work fine.

Comment: @besplash: I believe this is your only option - proper or nor proper programming. In my opinion the automation interface is badly designed but you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: @MartinLiversage any updates on this , or it is still the only option?

Comment: @Dragon I provided my answer six years ago. I don't think I have been using that API ever since so I have no updates for you.

Comment: @MartinLiversage no worries, will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on @"Martin Liversage" suggesting, here is a working C++ example tested with C# interop.

"AddAppFirewallRule" will only add the firewall rule if it doesn't exist.
"RemoveAppFirewallRule" will remove all firewall rules that match the exe path.

**C/C+**+

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netfw.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

#include "Exports.h"

HRESULT WFCOMInitialize(INetFwPolicy2** ppNetFwPolicy2)
{
    return CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetFwPolicy2), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(INetFwPolicy2), (void**)ppNetFwPolicy2);
}

extern "C"
{
    MyFrameworkOSNative_EXPORT int MyFrameworkOSNative_AddAppFirewallRule(int privateNetworks, int publicNetworks, int domainNetworks, wchar_t* exePath, wchar_t* name, wchar_t* groupName, wchar_t* desc, wchar_t* ports, int tcp, int udp)
    {
        // declare locals
        int result = 0;
        HRESULT addRuleResult;

        BSTR ruleName = SysAllocString(name);
        BSTR ruleGroup = SysAllocString(groupName);
        BSTR ruleDesc = SysAllocString(desc);
        BSTR ruleExe = SysAllocString(exePath);
        BSTR rulePorts = nullptr;
        if (ports != nullptr) rulePorts = SysAllocString(ports);

        INetFwPolicy2* policy = nullptr;
        INetFwRules* rules = nullptr;
        INetFwRule* rule = nullptr;
        long profilesBitMask = 0;

        HRESULT iterateResult = 0;
        IUnknown* rulesCollection = nullptr;
        IEnumVARIANT* variant = nullptr;
        CComVariant var = {};
        ULONG fetched = 0;
        bool found = false;

        // init
        if (FAILED(WFCOMInitialize(&policy))) goto Cleanup;
        if (FAILED(policy->get_Rules(&rules))) goto Cleanup;

        //if (FAILED(policy->get_CurrentProfileTypes(&profilesBitMask))) goto Cleanup;
        if (privateNetworks) profilesBitMask |= NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE;
        if (publicNetworks) profilesBitMask |= NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
        if (domainNetworks) profilesBitMask |= NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN;

        if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetFwRule), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(INetFwRule), (void**)&rule))) goto Cleanup;

        // setup rule
        rule->put_Name(ruleName);
        rule->put_Description(ruleDesc);
        rule->put_ApplicationName(ruleExe);
        if (tcp && udp) rule->put_Protocol(NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ANY);
        else if (tcp) rule->put_Protocol(NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP);
        else if (udp) rule->put_Protocol(NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP);
        if (rulePorts != nullptr) rule->put_LocalPorts(rulePorts);
        rule->put_Direction(NET_FW_RULE_DIR_MAX);
        rule->put_Grouping(ruleGroup);
        rule->put_Profiles(profilesBitMask);
        rule->put_Action(NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW);
        rule->put_Enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);

        // get rules enumerator
        if (FAILED(rules->get__NewEnum(&rulesCollection))) goto Cleanup;
        if (FAILED(rulesCollection->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IEnumVARIANT), (void**)&variant))) goto Cleanup;

        // enumerate rules to check if it already exists
        var.Clear();
        iterateResult = variant->Next(1, &var, &fetched);
        while (SUCCEEDED(iterateResult) && iterateResult != S_FALSE)
        {
            BSTR ruleEXEPath = nullptr;
            INetFwRule* existingRule = nullptr;
            long exitingRuleProfileBitMask = 0;
            if (FAILED((V_DISPATCH(&var))->QueryInterface(__uuidof(INetFwRule), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&existingRule)))) goto Cleanup;
            if (FAILED(existingRule->get_ApplicationName(&ruleEXEPath))) goto Cleanup;
            if (FAILED(existingRule->get_Profiles(&exitingRuleProfileBitMask))) goto Cleanup;
            if (ruleEXEPath != nullptr && wcscmp(ruleEXEPath, exePath) == 0 && exitingRuleProfileBitMask == profilesBitMask)// check if exe paths match
            {
                BSTR existingRuleName = nullptr;
                if (SUCCEEDED(existingRule->get_Name(&existingRuleName)))
                {
                    if (existingRuleName != nullptr)
                    {
                        if (wcscmp(ruleName, existingRuleName) == 0) found = true;
                        SysFreeString(existingRuleName);
                    }
                }
            }

            // cleanup iteration
            if (existingRule != nullptr)
            {
                existingRule->Release();
                existingRule = nullptr;
            }
            if (ruleEXEPath != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleEXEPath);

            // exit loop if found
            if (found) break;

            // get next item in collection
            var.Clear();
            iterateResult = variant->Next(1, &var, &fetched);
        }

        // add rule if it doesn't already exist
        if (!found)
        {
            addRuleResult = rules->Add(rule);
            if (FAILED(addRuleResult)) goto Cleanup;
        }

        result = 1;// success

        // cleanup resources
    Cleanup:;
        if (variant != nullptr) variant->Release();
        if (rulesCollection != nullptr) rulesCollection->Release();

        if (ruleName != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleName);
        if (ruleGroup != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleGroup);
        if (ruleDesc != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleDesc);
        if (ruleExe != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleExe);
        if (rulePorts != nullptr) SysFreeString(rulePorts);

        if (rule != nullptr) rule->Release();
        if (rules != nullptr) rules->Release();
        if (policy != nullptr) policy->Release();

        return result;
    }

    MyFrameworkOSNative_EXPORT int MyFrameworkOSNative_RemoveAppFirewallRule(wchar_t* exePath)
    {
        // declare locals
        int result = 0;

        INetFwPolicy2* policy = nullptr;
        INetFwRules* rules = nullptr;
        INetFwRule* rule = nullptr;
        long profilesBitMask = 0;

        HRESULT iterateResult = 0;
        IUnknown* rulesCollection = nullptr;
        IEnumVARIANT* variant = nullptr;
        CComVariant var = {};
        ULONG fetched = 0;
        bool found = false;

        // init
        if (FAILED(WFCOMInitialize(&policy))) goto Cleanup;
        if (FAILED(policy->get_Rules(&rules))) goto Cleanup;

        // get rules enumerator
        if (FAILED(rules->get__NewEnum(&rulesCollection))) goto Cleanup;
        if (FAILED(rulesCollection->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IEnumVARIANT), (void**)&variant))) goto Cleanup;

        // enumerate rules
        var.Clear();
        iterateResult = variant->Next(1, &var, &fetched);
        while (SUCCEEDED(iterateResult) && iterateResult != S_FALSE)
        {
            BSTR ruleEXEPath = nullptr;
            if (FAILED((V_DISPATCH(&var))->QueryInterface(__uuidof(INetFwRule), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&rule)))) goto Cleanup;
            if (FAILED(rule->get_ApplicationName(&ruleEXEPath))) goto Cleanup;
            if (ruleEXEPath != nullptr && wcscmp(ruleEXEPath, exePath) == 0)// check if exe paths match
            {
                found = true;
                SysFreeString(ruleEXEPath);
                BSTR ruleName = nullptr;
                if (FAILED(rule->get_Name(&ruleName)))
                {
                    if (ruleName != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleName);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }
                if (FAILED(rules->Remove(ruleName)))
                {
                    if (ruleName != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleName);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }
                if (ruleName != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleName);

                // get next item in collection
                var.Clear();
                iterateResult = variant->Next(1, &var, &fetched);
                continue;// continue to scan for more rules with same criteria
            }

            // cleanup iteration
            if (rule != nullptr)
            {
                rule->Release();
                rule = nullptr;
            }
            if (ruleEXEPath != nullptr) SysFreeString(ruleEXEPath);

            // get next item in collection
            var.Clear();
            iterateResult = variant->Next(1, &var, &fetched);
        }
        
        if (!found) goto Cleanup;
        result = 1;// success

        // cleanup resources
    Cleanup:;
        if (variant != nullptr) variant->Release();
        if (rulesCollection != nullptr) rulesCollection->Release();

        if (rule != nullptr) rule->Release();
        if (rules != nullptr) rules->Release();
        if (policy != nullptr) policy->Release();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("MyFramework.OS.Native.dll")]
private static unsafe extern int VMyFrameworkOSNative_AddAppFirewallRule(int privateNetworks, int publicNetworks, int domainNetworks, char* exePath, char* name, char* groupName, char* desc, char* ports, int tcp, int udp);

[DllImport("MyFramework.OS.Native.dll")]
private static unsafe extern int MyFrameworkOSNative_RemoveAppFirewallRule(char* exePath);

public static unsafe bool AddAppFirewallRule(bool privateNetworks, bool publicNetworks, bool domainNetworks, string exePath, string ruleName, string ruleDesc, int port = -1, bool tcp = true, bool udp = true)
{
    // ensure COM is init
    Ole32.CoInitialize(IntPtr.Zero);

    // invoke native method
    string portValue = port.ToString();
    fixed (char* exePathPtr = exePath)
    fixed (char* ruleNamePtr = ruleName)
    fixed (char* ruleDescPtr = ruleDesc)
    fixed (char* portValuePtr = portValue)
    {
        return MyFrameworkOSNative_AddAppFirewallRule
        (
            privateNetworks ? 1 : 0,
            publicNetworks ? 1 : 0,
            domainNetworks ? 1 : 0,
            exePathPtr,
            ruleNamePtr, ruleNamePtr,
            ruleDescPtr,
            port > 0 ? portValuePtr : null,
            tcp ? 1 : 0, udp ? 1 : 0
        ) != 0;
    }
}

public static unsafe bool RemoveAppFirewallRule(string exePath)
{
    // ensure COM is init
    Ole32.CoInitialize(IntPtr.Zero);

    // invoke native method
    fixed (char* exePathPtr = exePath)
    {
        return VMyFrameworkOSNative_RemoveAppFirewallRule(exePathPtr) != 0;
    }
}
```

**UnitTests**

```
[Fact]
public void AddAppFirewallRule()
{
    using (var lib = new LibHandle("MyFramework.OS.Native.dll"))
    {
        Assert.True(NetworkUtils.AddAppFirewallRule(true, true, false, @"<Path-To-Exe>", "TestRule", "Test Rule Desc"));
    }
}

[Fact]
public void RemoveAppFirewallRule()
{
    using (var lib = new LibHandle("MyFramework.OS.Native.dll"))
    {
        Assert.True(NetworkUtils.RemoveAppFirewallRule(@"<Path-To-Exe>"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void RemoveFirewallRules(string RuleName = "BreakermindCom")
{
    try
    {
        Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
        INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
        var currentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;               

        // Lista rules
        // List<INetFwRule> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule>();

        foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
        {
            // Add rule to list
            // RuleList.Add(rule);
            // Console.WriteLine(rule.Name);
            if (rule.Name.IndexOf(RuleName) != -1)
            {
                // Now add the rule
                INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));                     
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove(rule.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(rule.Name + " has been deleted from Firewall Policy");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error delete rule from firewall");
    }}
```

Look at this

Comment: does not solve the duplicate names problem regarding the question